# jQuery automatic scroll / slideshow

Tags: jquery, playback

Could i modify this existing code to automatically scroll through the list items to display the content?

Sorry, the: ul li a {} links.

Maybe using "interval" method?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabNav a').click(function() {
        var curChildIndex = $(this).parent().prevAll().length + 1;
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');
        $(this).parent().parent().prev('.tabContainer').children('.current').fadeOut('fast',function() {
            $(this).parent().children('div:nth-child('+curChildIndex+')').fadeIn('fast',function() {
                $(this).addClass('current');
            });
            $(this).removeClass('current');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are millions of plugins that do exactly that. Let's not reinvent the wheel and try one of [these](http://bradblogging.com/jquery/9-jquery-slideshow-applications-you-cannot-miss/) or [these](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/).

Edit:
There are special timer plugins as well, take a look at [this](http://jquery.offput.ca/every/) one.